# Google Api, how can I refresh user token when I have acces token and previous refresh token

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, google-api

Is it possible to refresh Google Api token when I have previous refresh token and access token using pure php, without Google Api library? I am storing in database many users refresh and access tokens.

I am using url from this address:

https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer?hl=en#creatingcred

and using this address:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?
 scope=email%20profile&
 state=security_token%3D138r5719ru3e1%26url%3Dhttps://oa2cb.example.com/myHome&
 redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Foauth2-login-demo.appspot.com%2Fcode&,
 response_type=code&
 client_id=812741506391.apps.googleusercontent.com
```

All the time I am being redirected somewhere, and not getting new `access token`.
But, why do I have to put `redirect_uri`? 
Additionally under my Google API Manager in Credential section I have some `Client ID` and `Client secret` but `Client ID` `1076711322609-s9mrrfp3t8gto2qkrj4ud3jjhr3rr0ph.apps.googleusercontent.com` is different than this one `client_id=812741506391.apps.googleusercontent.com` Why?

So the question is, how can I get access to users Google API endpoint using their access tokens, and refresh those tokens every hour using PHP (REST calls) without any prompts, logins and passwords. Is it even possible?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a new access_token you take the refresh_token that you have stored in your database and **HTTP Post** it to the following url. 
Note: grant_type=refresh_token

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
client_id={ClientId}.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret={ClientSecret}&refresh_token=1/ffYmfI0sjR54Ft9oupubLzrJhD1hZS5tWQcyAvNECCA&grant_type=refresh_token
```

**The response**

> { "access_token" :
>   "ya29.1.AADtN_XK16As2ZHlScqOxGtntIlevNcasMSPwGiE3pe5ANZfrmJTcsI3ZtAjv4sDrPDRnQ",
>   "token_type" : "Bearer", "expires_in" : 3600 }

Comment: Should I use app ClientId and app ClientSecret, or user ClientId and user ClientSecret?

Comment: Is there a difference?  Use the client id and secrete that where used to create the refreshtoken

Comment: You had right, I used wrong `refresh_token`. In Google API Playground `refresh_token` could be different that refresh and access token to you app

Answer (score 1):

So after many attempts I found working solution.

**===EDIT====** 
@DaImTo answer is much better

**POST**

```
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/refreshAccessToken
```

**Headers:**

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

**Body:**

```
{
    "refresh_token": "YOUR_PREVIOUS_REFRESH_TOKEN"
}
```